# Java Grid Layout Order

Tags: java, swing, grid-layout

I have 3 toggle buttons which can turn on/off three panels in a grid layout, let's call them panels A, B, and C.
I want to achieve that no matter what order I turn the panels on, they will end up in order (A B C). Right now, I just use `add()` which adds the item to the end meaning they end up in the same order I clicked the buttons.
I am updating the grid layout with the right number of rows and cols depending on how many buttons are active

Using `add(jPanel, 0, n)` where n is 0, 1, 2 for the A, B, and C panels throws an illegal component position exception when I use an index which exceeds the number of rows or cols

Comment: You don't say what's on the panels, but you could create the JPanels and toggle buttons in one step, disable the JPanels that should be disabled in a second step, and enable the JPanel when the toggle button is left-clicked in a third and subsequent steps.

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). And please, let's give the panels descriptive names and *not* call them `A`, `B` and `C`!

Answer (score 1):

The ActionListener can be shared for each toggle button.

The code would be something like:

1. remove all the panels from the parent panel
2. iterate through all the toggle buttons and for each selected toggle button add back in the panel at the end
3. revalidate() the main panel
4. repaint() the main panel

The removing/adding of the panels will only occur when the revalidate()/repaint() is done to the user won't notice any effect of the inital removing of all the panels.